# Passing Json object from my action filter class to my ajax.actionlink

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, linq

I have the following action filter class inside my asp.net MVC web application, which perform a custom authorization check:-

```
public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{ 
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //code goes here….
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var viewResult = new JsonResult();
            viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "You are not authorized to perform this Action." });
            filterContext.Result = viewResult;
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}}}
```

And I have the following ajax.actinolink which will call an action method and perform the authorization check:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Related Servers", "CustomerServer","Customer",
    new {customerID = Model.ORG_ID},
    new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "detail"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress",

 OnSuccess="detailsuccess"}
```

And the Onsuccess script is :-

```
function detailsuccess(data) {
   if (data.IsSuccess == "Unauthorized") {

       jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthorized Access');
   }}
```

the action method is :-

```
 [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Read", Model = "Server")]
     public ActionResult CustomerServer(int customerID,int page=1) {
```

But the problem I am facing is that incase the action filter return Json object , then the Onsuccess script insidee my ajax link will not receive the Json object and no JAlert will be displayed, and even the Onsuccess script will not fire ?

Comment: John, sorry I don't have time to post code right now. Just leaving this comment instead: The client-side handler scripted by Microsoft that receives the ajax response from the server is expecting html. When it receives json instead, it doesn't know what to do.
1. Your filter should set the appropriate unauthorized status code (401) instead of returning json.
2. You should create a javascript "detailError" function and add it to the "OnError" property of the ActionLink in your razor file just as you did with the "OnSuccess" property

Comment: thanks for the reply , but when i use ajax.beginform on some functionalities instead of ajax.actionlink i am able to pass the JSON object to the Onsuccess script..